# Alamofire: Follow HTTP redirects (or not)

Tags: ios, redirect, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to configure Alamofire to follow redirects (or not) on a per-request basis.

Alamofire has a private internal class `SessionDelegate` which serves as the `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` for the current URL session. `SessionDelegate` does implement the relevant delegate method, `URLSession(session:, task:, willPerformHTTPRedirection response:, request:, completionHandler:)` which is exactly what I want.

Even better, the delegate's implementation consults a custom variable closure named `taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection` to determine how to handle the redirect - again, exactly what I want!

And as far as I can tell, that closure is always `nil` by default -- it is not assigned to internally by Alamofire -- which suggests that it is intended to let the user assign a closure to it.

The problem: I cannot access this private `SessionDelegate` class to assign a closure to its `taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection` variable. It is a private class and it is not visible to my Swift files. What is the proper means of configuring an Alamofire request to (not) follow redirects?

Comment: Alamofire as AFnetworking respects HTTP standards. so I asume it follows up redirects automatically. I know because I've changed domains before and the app would follow up the redirect with no problems.

Comment: AFNetworking can be configured to not follow redirects. Alamofire certainly has the foundation to do the same.

Comment: As Alamofire is not that much code and is quite young library, I would just fork the library and implement the functionality myself using taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection as you correctly spotted. Then just submit a PR. It seems that @mattt put those hooks there in place from the beginning even if they are not yet used by Alamofire public API.

Comment: @TeemuKurppa: You are correct, of course, [so I did](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/350). :)

Comment: This has been bothering me a long time. I didn't notice the selector switch at the bottom until I had another look thanks to this question. I just set the closure manually in Alamofire which doesn't look as nice as your solution but if anyone else sees this and needs a quick solution until this gets merged it should work. Thank you!

Comment: I opened a bounty to get this issue more attention. See also Mr. Hersh's initial implementation at https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/350.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flexible redirect handling is now in Alamofire thanks to [another pull request](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/317) and is available with Alamofire `1.2.0`.

Comment: I create custom class of `SessionDelegate`. `Alamofire.SessionDelegate` property is not settable. How to stop re-direction in Alamofire.

Answer (score 7):

You can use it like this

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let sessionDelegate = Manager.SessionDelegate()
sessionDelegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionWithCompletion = {
   (session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, response: NSHTTPURLResponse,
    newRequest: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: NSURLRequest? -> Void) in

    // do something
}

let manager = Manager(configuration: configuration, delegate: sessionDelegate)
```

Alamofire Manager keeps the `delegate` as strong so you can be sure

```
public let delegate: SessionDelegate
```

but remember [willPerformHTTPRedirection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate/URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:)

> This method is called only for tasks in default and ephemeral sessions. Tasks in background sessions automatically follow redirects.

also good to read about fundamentals [Handling Redirects and Other Request Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/RequestChanges.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think that issue has been discussed long time ago , check this **[issue](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/71)**

matt's answer was clear though :

> I presume various closure-typed properties in SessionDelegate,
>   TaskDelegate, DataTaskDelegate and DownloadTaskDelegate are intended
>   to be used by clients to extend/override particular delegates
>   behavior.

---

> Actually, that's incorrect. These are implemented internally for the
>   sake of completeness. Any functionality intended for the end user
>   would be exposed on **Manager** or **Request**.

Anyway I see that the bounty is offered by Aaron , while Jonathan forked his own **[version](https://github.com/jhersh/Alamofire/commit/bbdee79eefff2fc4f57f392f6494473538850fae)** , so why dont you use that fork ?